# Remove container class from rendered component which gets rendered through router-outlet in angular

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-router

Whenever a component gets rendered via router-outlet in angular, a container class gets added to it.. Is it possible to prevent it from happening so that it behaves similar to the rendering done via using component selector? 
actually I need a component's content to use full page width but this isn't happening